# Past perfect as explanation

Tags: past-perfect

> Before the ambulance arrived, the injured man **died** .

No need for past perfect here.

> As the ambulance approached the scene, the driver noticed that no one at all was attending to the injured man. This was **because**, before the ambulance arrived, the injured man had died. No one was looking after the injured man, because he **had died**.

Past perfect is needed as **explanation** but the sequence of time without it would be crystal clear. Would it be possible to use past simple?

> My dad was furious **because** I scratched his car.

So why not past perfect for scratched as it is an explaination of why my dad is furious?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand from the previous question and answer, [past perfect to emphasize a changement](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/80711/past-perfect-to-emphasize-a-changement). Why do you keep asking the same question? Did you try the search to find out similar questions before asking this question?

Comment: 99% duplicate, [Is it possible to be grammatically correct without using past perfect?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5508/is-it-possible-to-be-grammatically-correct-without-using-past-perfect), 99.9% duplicate, [When is the past perfect exactly needed?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/when-is-the-past-perfect-exactly-needed), you can find many related questions [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=past+perfect+past+simple),

Comment: That's not like that, @Rathony: [“Repetition is the mother of learning, the father of action, which makes it the architect of accomplishment.”](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/887600-repetition-is-the-mother-of-learning-the-father-of-action).

Comment: @LucianSava I can't agree with you more on the point. The Original Poster can read the linked questions and answers repeatedly, but not ask the same question repeatedly. I recommend you read this, [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates).